# How can I keep my buttons/input underneath my image?

Tags: javascript, css

My idea is to have 6 items (pictures) with buttons underneath able to click *Quantity* and *Add to Basket*, however I am falling short with my CSS.

I have 6 `div`s with a class of `controlpic`. I am finding that rather than keeping underneath the images the inputs and buttons are on the right side.

```css
.controlpic{
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="controlpic">
  <img class="img" src="jsbook1.png">
  <button class "clear">-</button>
  <input>
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tidied, corrected grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet for you to look at:
https://jsfiddle.net/sc3y8z83/

I hope this helps!

**HTML**

```
<div class="controlpic">
  <img class="img" src="http://orig09.deviantart.net/b7a4/f/2012/062/d/5/blue_icon_pattern_by_killer_icons-d4rkk2f.jpg">
  <button class="clear">-</button>
  <input type="text">
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.controlpic{
   overflow: auto;
}
.img{
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: yes it does thank you! that is what i was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your css

```
.controlpic img{
   display:block;
}
```